# Clip-path using svg html element is not working

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to clip an image using a svg but it is not working.

Follows the code:

```css
img {
  clip-path: url(#svgPath);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath">
      <rect x="286.5" y="95" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="274" height="274"></rect>
      <rect x="286.5" y="391" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="274" height="274"></rect>
      <rect x="582.5" y="95" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="274" height="274"></rect>
      <rect x="582.5" y="391" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="274" height="274"></rect>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" />
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `-webkit-` vendor prefix as chrome, opera and safari consider `clip-path` to be an experimental feature.

More on `clip-path` browser support can be found on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath);
          clip-path: url(#svgPath);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" />
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath">
      <rect x="286.5" y="95" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="274" height="274" fill="#ffffff"></rect>
      <rect x="286.5" y="391" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="274" height="274"></rect>
      <rect x="582.5" y="95" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="274" height="274"></rect>
      <rect x="582.5" y="391" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="274" height="274"></rect>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```